# Can't read video file in OpenCV after video capture

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, video-processing, webcam, video-capture

I'm capturing a file from my webcam and save it:

```
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('H','2','6','4')
out = cv2.VideoWriter(self.output_video_fn, fourcc, 20.0, (w, h), isColor = True)
flag = False
while not flag:
        success, buf = self.cam.read()
        print("******* Success is ", success)
        print(buf)
        if success == True:
            print("Wait")
            cv2.waitKey(1500) #todo delete after loop is good
            print("Here")
            flag = True
            # self.IAPS_TASK_IS_FINISHED = True
            # print(buf)
            out.write(buf)
    self.cam.release()
    print("Saved video to ", self.output_video_fn)
```

After saving it I'm trying to play it. I can't play in VLC (size is 162KB and it says the duration is 00:00). I'm trying to play in OpenCV:

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(self.output_video_fn)

while(cap.isOpened()):
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        print("Ret is ", ret)
        print("frame is ", frame)

        cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

But Ret is  False and frame is  None.
What could the problem be?

Answer (score 0):

I've only used OpenCV with its C and C++ APIs, but I've noticed VideoWriter problems before if you are attempting to write image data containing an Alpha channel, or if the codec isn't available on the system. Some environments don't don't seem to cause exceptions if the codec doesn't exist. Can you confirm you have H264 available?

Comment: How can I ensure I have H264 available?

Comment: That's system dependent. What OS are you using? I'd recommend temporarily changing your code to use a codec that OpenCV supported natively - try: fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('M','J','P','G') then see if VLC works then.

Comment: If you're on windows the KLiteCodecPack should give you H264 capability

Comment: my two cents, going for XVID in the codec and .avi for output video has worked for me.